# Integrate React and Springboot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

What is the best way to integrate React and Spring Boot but still make development possible?  I'm following a procedure outlined here https://dev.to/arpan_banerjee7/run-react-frontend-and-springboot-backend-on-the-same-port-and-package-them-as-a-single-artifact-14pa which essentially copies the contents of the React build directory to the target directory, so that Spring can serve the files at runtime.  The React build process combines all of the React js files into several compressed js files.  The problem with that is then I see requests such as this: `GET /static/js/2.09068613.chunk.js`, which makes it difficult to know what's going on.

I could run the node server separately, but then the react files are served from localhost:3000, which means it's on a different port from the server and things need to be configured differently.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Would be nice to know what the downvotes are for.  I'm been researching this for days and have tried several approaches.  I'm primarily a backend developer, so relatively new to React and Javascript frameworks.

Comment: during dev of ui you could rely on'proxy' directive to call your backend without cors issue. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should intercept all mappings not matching backend paths (usually `/` unless specific backend mapping was selected) and route them to the `index.html` file, further communication will work by the file imports from the main HTML file.

**That being said**, unless you have a very specific issue you're dealing with preventing you from using two different services, you should thrive to separate the two in order to avoid any rare and hard to debug issues or like the following ongoing development issues:

1. **Scalability** - if scaling is an option in the future being able to scale the services separately according to demand would be a great advantage and a resource saver.
2. **Growing pain** - Generally, even if it's going to be able to handle the load on its own just fine, it's better to separate the service in case you'll want to add functionality or even more standalone services to not have to deal with the separation burden in a later stage.
3. **Separation of responsibility** - getting a clear view on each service purpose will help to consolidate similar actions to specific and separate services removing duplications and weird workaround to keep everything together
4. **Security** - if each service has access only to the data its needs it helps to prevent privilege escalation through the frontend application and with secure HTTPS communication all data transfer is encrypted
5. **Small downtime** - when you have different services for each part of the application stack you can more easily pinpoint where the problem originates from and fix it faster and in a simpler fashion

Comment: Are you suggesting that even in production, they remain as 2 separate servers?

Comment: especially in production, if one backend consumes too much memory it will bring down the entire application stack, you can run them separately on the same server connecting with the machine internal network as regular applications or with containers to streamline the process and make configuration easier

Comment: Wouldn't index.html still need to be in a location where the backend server could find it?

Comment: if you have another process serving the frontend files you shouldn't deal with that (to clarify that's what I'm suggesting). [here's](https://www.forbes.com/sites/forbestechcouncil/2018/07/19/seven-reasons-why-a-websites-front-end-and-back-end-should-be-kept-separate/?sh=10376fc64fca) a nice article to sum some more reasons to do so. it's better for security, for good practices, for separation of responsibility, etc...

Comment: added more reasons to answer

Comment: Problem I have is that there are certain cases where the backend needs to route to the front-end.  For example, with Spring Security.  So are you suggesting that I hard-code the front-end url in those cases?

Comment: since I don't have full access to your project (and this is not the setting for such checks) I wouldn't give a definitive answer, though I would suggest if doing so to use an environment variable or import the URL through a `.properties` file

Comment: @PeterKronenberg if the answer was helpful I'd appreciate you accepting it with the checkmark near it

Comment: Helpful, but still not sure it will work for me.  I'm using Spring Security, which means that the Spring server has to be the one that the user is browsing to.  I.e., localhost:8080 and not the React server at localhost:3000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238256/discussion-between-noam-yizraeli-and-peter-kronenberg).